# What are workarounds to refresh an individual vector tile zoomlayer in mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have a datasource consisting of vector tile points. When I currently add a new point on my client, the server adds it to the database and using an afterhook from sequalize runs a command which updates the relevant tiles for all relevant zoomlayers. Then it shows up in my client at all zoomlayers (when zooming in & out after adding the point), so it is working as it should, except on the zoomlayer on which the point was added as that tile did not refresh yet... It will eventually appear when you refresh the page for example.

As currently you can [not](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2633) refresh individual tiles in the client, I need somehow to work around this. How can this be done? Preferably of course without a refresh.

The setup is as follows:

- base map: a vector tile source from server A
- datapoints: a vector tile source from server B which is a separate
  layer on the base map called 'datapoints'

### Code

```
axios.post('urlServerB', newpointGeojsonobject)
  .then(function (response) {
    map.removeLayer(datapointsLayerID)
    map.removeSource('datapoints')
    addDatapointsSource(map)
    map.addLayer(datapoints)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @JGallardo I added it to the end of my question. Sorry, but I can not get the indentation right to make it show as code... Normally this is no problem, but the promise indentation is causing me a headache! Maybe you know how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand "When I currently add a new point on my client, the server updates the relevant tiles." - what code are you using to "add a new point", and why would that cause the server to do anything?

Comment: I edited the question which hopefully answers your question. Also made clear that I am talking about ZOOMlayers, where applicable.

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ Any idea? I saw other questions -with answers- from you which are somewhat similar!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is probably that the browser has already cached your vector tiles, yet the content of them has changed. You can work around that by replacing your vector tile source with a slightly different URL, by adding nonsense parameters.

For instance:

```
  map.removeSource('osm') ;
  map.addSource('osm', {    
    "type": "vector",
    "tiles": ["https://tile.mapzen.com/mapzen/vector/v1/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt?api_key=vector-tiles-LM25tq4&update=" + Math.random()]
  });
```

https://codepen.io/stevebennett/pen/LzNjVv

Click on the map to refresh the data source. It does flicker a bit. You may be able to work around that by disabling repaint for a second or so, or using some other technique mask the behaviour.

Comment: Looks good. I actually succeeded by setting a Cache-Control header which prohibits caching, which works. But since caching in itself is nice, your solution would be better. Problem I have when I add the Math.random() is that I get a CORS error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I will see if I can get around that.

Comment: Ah, in my case I needed to add the question mark and then the Math.random(). Works great now!

Comment: Yes, so the feature they describe is more important when you don't control the tileserver. But when you do, this works fine!